# Passing parameters instead of globals

Tags: python, function, parameters

I've been using Python for a while but I've never really learnt how to pass parameters and I got into the bad habit of using global variables, but now I'm trying to learn and it isn't going great. Is anybody able to spot what I'm doing wrong here:

Simplified version of code:

```
clickLoad = 0

def get_length(clickLoad):
    listLength = 305     #(Sample Value)

    if listLength < 101:
       clickLoad = 0
    elif 100 < listLength < 201:
       clickLoad = 1
    elif 201 <= listLength < 301:
       clickLoad = 2
    elif 301 <= listLength < 401:
       clickLoad = 3
    return clickLoad

def load_more(clickLoad):
    print(clickLoad)      # Testing value, prints 0
    while clickLoad < 0:
       # Do some stuff
       clickLoad -= 1
    return clickLoad

get_length(clickLoad)
load_more(clickLoad)
```

The value of clickLoad never seems to change from 0. When listLength = 305, I would expect it to be 3.

Comment: That a fairly basic issue regarding *variable scopes*, most python tutorials cover this subject, you should probably find one and read through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clickLoad = 0

def get_length(clickLoad):
    listLength = 305     #(Sample Value)

    if listLength < 101:
       clickLoad = 0
    elif 100 < listLength < 201:
       clickLoad = 1
    elif 201 <= listLength < 301:
       clickLoad = 2
    elif 301 <= listLength < 401:
       clickLoad = 3
    return( clickLoad)

def load_more(clickLoad):
    print(clickLoad)      # Testing value, prints 0
    while clickLoad < 0:
       # Do some stuff
       clickLoad -= 1
    return clickLoad

s = get_length(clickLoad)
load_more(s)
```

try this as you are not storing the the value returned by the function to the next function before calling, thus its taking the global one

Answer (score 1):

As you do not use global no more, the changes you make on clickLoad are only made inside the function. You do well returning clickLoad Tho you forgot to re-affect the new returned value to the global variable clickLoad (which still is global as you can access it wherever in your script)
So, this should work

```
clickLoad = 0

def get_length(clickLoad):
    listLength = 305     #(Sample Value)

    if listLength < 101:
       clickLoad = 0
    elif 100 < listLength < 201:
       clickLoad = 1
    elif 201 <= listLength < 301:
       clickLoad = 2
    elif 301 <= listLength < 401:
       clickLoad = 3
    return clickLoad

def load_more(clickLoad):
    print(clickLoad)      # Testing value, prints 0
    while clickLoad < 0:
       # Do some stuff
       clickLoad -= 1
    return clickLoad

clickLoad = get_length(clickLoad)
clickLoad = load_more(clickLoad)
```

Answer (score 0):

When a function returns a value, it means the value is provided to the calling function for further use. But it is not written to a global variable.

To get what you are looking for, try:

```
clickLoad = get_length(clickLoad)
clickLoad = load_more(clickLoad)
```

This is very basic understanding of how functions work, you should read a tutorial about it.